# ConfigurationManager.Appsettings[""] Sharing config file

Tags: file, sharing, appsettings, configurationmanager

Currently, I have 2 windows services that i would like them to be sharing from a single app.config file.

How i can tell ConfigurationManager class to load settings from a single file that would be shared by 2 services?

With ConfigurationManager.Appsettings[""] requires, each service needs to have its own config file. It would be nice if the user can just configure one file instead of 2 files with similar settings.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<appSettings configSource="appSettings.shared.config"/>
```

http://sunali.com/2008/01/23/configsource-property-dividing-configuration-files-into-pieces/